# How to include Java library into Adobe Air (native extension for Android) project from Bintray or Maven

Tags: android, air, adobe, bintray

We have a client that has an app written in Adobe Air (ActionScript, HTML, JavaScript) and it uses native extension for Android. We are providing Android library written in Java through bintray. Since we don't have experience with Adobe Air can anyone tell me if it is possible to include our Android linrary into clients Adobe Air app? We know that it is possible to include .jar but nowdays the common way is using gradle so we don't want to export .jar or .aar if not necessary. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, using an Adobe Native Extension:

- first, your client has to implement the ActionScript side
- secondly, you need to write specific Java entrypoints in your Java Library, to catch calls and input parameters, process requests and reply with output parameters
- finally, your client has to pack your Library in its AIR archive

Each of these 3 steps is fully described, with code snippets in AS3 and Java, on the reference documentation from Adobe:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/air_extensions.pdf